# How to fix Eclipse with OpenJDK 9

Tags: java, eclipse, openjdk

I have installed OpenJDK 9 in Ubuntu 17.10. I wanted to start developing in Java, and I did setup JAVA_HOME variable and did some stuff I found on the internet. I can compile a Java program and run it, but I cannot install an IDE, which would be really necessary.

The error message is:

> An error has occurred. See the log file
>   /home/erik/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1531145712071.log.

The log file contains:

```
!SESSION 2018-07-09 16:15:11.911 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=9-Ubuntu
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.423
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.429
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.435
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.435
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.435
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.436
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.436
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.436
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-07-09 16:15:12.437
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Hi Gameerik and welcome to askUbuntu! Format you post according to this link https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code. This will help to make the post more readable. E.g.:  You can also select the code and press CTRL+K to toggle indenting as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eclipse snap package from the default Ubuntu repositories is perfect for Java programming because it is bundled with a Java development environment. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install eclipse --classic
```

This command will install the latest Photon Release 4.8 version of Eclipse IDE for Java Developers which was updated 8 days ago. Eclipse changed its codename policy so that Eclipse releases from September 2018 and onward are named after the year and month of the release date, for example Eclipse 2020-06. This naming scheme also applies to the eclipse snap package.

Photon JDT supports Java 9 completely:

- The Eclipse compiler for Java (ECJ) implements all the new Java 9 language enhancements.
- Updated significant features to support Java Modules, such as compiler, search and many editor features.

Answer (score 2):

Though I always prefer packages from the Ubuntu distro, I make an exception for Eclipse because it (a) is trivial to install, (b) must be installed as user (no root required or recommended), and (c) it manages its own updates and plugins very well - including rollbacks, etc.

The instructions below work for all Eclipse IDEs (Java, C/C++, Web, PHP, etc).

1. Install the JDK

   ```
   sudo apt install default-jdk
   ```
2. Download the latest Eclipse installer from [eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).  Currently this is [Eclipse Photon](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/photon/R/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz).
3. Unpack it in a directory of your choice

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/eclipse/installer
   tar -C ~/eclipse/installer -xzf ~/Downloads/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz
   ```
4. Run the installer

   ```
   cd ~/eclipse/installer
   ./eclipse-inst
   ```
5. Pick your IDE and follow the prompts

When done, start your IDE with the `eclipse` script in the directory `eclipse` underneath where you installed the IDE.

To **uninstall** any Eclipse IDE, simply `rm -r` its installation directory.   If you are obsessive about kruft pollution then also `rm -rf ~/.eclipse`.