# Cannot start eclipse

Tags: launcher, eclipse

Addition, I don't think that my question is a duplication because my log file is different from what is in other question,also in other question it says "I have installed OpenJDK 9 in Ubuntu" - i didn't install explicitly OpenJDK. But if you people think that it makes sense for me to run command
sudo snap install eclipse --classic  i Would gladly do it, but keep in mind that i need it for C++, not Java development

I am absolutely new to Linux and ubuntu. But i am a seasoned windows C++ developer.
I am trying to do a project in Linux.

- I installed Ubuntu - no problems.
- Installed build essentials (`sudo apt-get install build-essentials`) - no problem.
- Then i installed Eclipse - `sudo apt-get install eclipse`. Installation went thru without visible complains.
- But When i tried to start eclipse it says

  ```
  An error has occurred.  See the log file /home/boris/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1534345120581.log
  ```

  Log file says:

  ```
  !SESSION Wed Aug 15 10:58:40 EDT 2018 ------------------------------------------
  !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-08-15 10:58:40.688
  !MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
  !STACK
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
  at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
  ```

People please help. What should i do to overcome this issue?

Best regards,

Boris Pitel

Comment: Apart from the bug, for C/C++ development you'll probably want to install `eclipse-cdt`, not `eclipse`.

Comment: @karel, no, close after all. I've just added the "from source" alternative to that question, which covers all IDEs.

Comment: Boris, you should be able to install the C++ IDE using the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065731/134479)

Comment: Eclipse 3.8 is far too old to run with Java 9. Use the current version of Eclipse (4.8 Photon).

Comment: Thank you people! :) - i installed Photon release 4.8.0 and everything became magically better. Some how though, I know have 2 eclipses on my poor machine. How to get rid of old one without damaging new one?